# Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-whitelist': Error using forcedroid command line

Tags: android, cordova, salesforce, salesforce-ios-sdk, salesforce-communities

Here is screendshot of what i got when I run `forcedroid create`:
Please i saw many discussion on stackoverflow like [failed to install cordova-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316531/failed-to-install-cordova-plugin-whitelist-using-forcedroid-for-creating-android) but there is no answer.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

this will fix the problem:

1) Add the environment variables, ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME ( giving the path of the folder SDKand the one of JDKin the value).

2) In the system valriable PATH, add the path of the platform-tools the one of the tools folder.

It will fix your error successfully.

Comment: *My path is * /home/anuj/.local/share/umake/bin:/home/anuj/bin:/home/anuj/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/home/anuj/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/anuj/Android/Sdk/platform-tools  but it isstill showing error .